# How to change the order of subplots matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, subplot

I have a data frame that contains average concentrations for 4 different sites based on season and year. The code I wrote produces a figure for each site, with four subplots for each season. Year is on the y-axis and concentration is on the x-axis.
Here's the link to my data: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1mVAsjRiFmMXaW0F8HBhadi1ZQPcUGIa7/view?usp=sharing

The issue is that the code automatically plots the subplots as

fall - spring

summer - winter

I want them to plot in chronological order, because that makes more sense that alphabetical:

spring - summer

fall - winter

Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import statsmodels.formula.api as smf
import scipy.stats

main_dataframe = pd.read_csv('NOx_sznl.csv')
main_dataframe.rename(columns={'NOx_3168':'Banning NOx', 'NOx_2199':'Palm Springs NOx', 'NOx_2551':'El Centro NOx', 'NOx_3135':'Calexico NOx'}, inplace=True)

col = list(main_dataframe.columns)
col.remove('Year')
col.remove('Season')

for ind,station in enumerate(col):
    
        df_new = main_dataframe[['Season', 'Year', col[ind]]]
###here I tried to reorder the seasons in the dataframe
        df_new = df_new.set_index('Season')
        df_new = df_new.loc[['Spring', 'Summer', 'Fall', 'Winter'], :]
        df_new = df_new.reset_index()
###but it didn't change the outcome
        df_new = df_new.set_index('Year')
        
        # df_new['Betty Jo Mcneece Receiving Home'].astype('float')
        df_new[col[ind]] = df_new[col[ind]]        


        grouped = df_new.groupby('Season')
        
        rowlength = grouped.ngroups/2                         # fix up if odd number of groups
        fig, axs = plt.subplots(figsize=(15,10), 
                                nrows=2, ncols=int(rowlength),     # fix as above
                                gridspec_kw=dict(hspace=0.4))#, sharex='col', sharey='row') # Much control of gridspec

        targets = zip(grouped.groups.keys(), axs.flatten())
        for i, (key, ax) in enumerate(targets):
            ax.plot(grouped.get_group(key)[col[ind]], marker='o', color='orange')
            ax.set_ylim(0,)
            ax.set_yticks(ax.get_yticks(),size=12)
            #ax.set_xlim(2009,2020)
            ax.set_xticks(np.arange(2009,2020,1))
            ax.set_xticklabels(ax.get_xticks(), rotation = 45, size=12)
        fig.suptitle("%s"%col[ind], fontsize=30)    
#         ax.set_title('%s')
        plt.subplot(221)
        plt.gca().set_title('Fall', fontsize=20)
        plt.subplot(222)
        plt.gca().set_title('Spring', fontsize=20)
        plt.subplot(223)
        plt.gca().set_title('Summer', fontsize=20)
        plt.subplot(224)
        plt.gca().set_title('Winter', fontsize=20)
        plt.show()
```

I would apppreciate any help rearranging the subplots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order of the subplots is given by `grouped.groups.keys()` in `targets = zip(grouped.groups.keys(), axs.flatten())` but the problem is further upstream in `grouped = df_new.groupby('Season')` which is where `grouped.groups.keys()` comes from. `df.groupby()` automatically sorts alphabetically unless you do `sort=False`, so `grouped = df_new.groupby('Season', sort=False)` should follow the order you provided when you made `df_new`.

Here is what your code looks like on my end so you can have an exact copy.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import statsmodels.formula.api as smf
import scipy.stats

main_dataframe = pd.read_csv('NOx_sznl.csv')
main_dataframe.rename(columns={'NOx_3168': 'Banning NOx',
                               'NOx_2199': 'Palm Springs NOx',
                               'NOx_2551': 'El Centro NOx',
                               'NOx_3135': 'Calexico NOx'},
                      inplace=True)

col = list(main_dataframe.columns)
col.remove('Year')
col.remove('Season')

for ind, station in enumerate(col):

    df_new = main_dataframe[['Season', 'Year', col[ind]]]
    ###here I tried to reorder the seasons in the dataframe
    df_new = df_new.set_index('Season')
    df_new = df_new.loc[['Spring', 'Summer', 'Fall', 'Winter'], :]
    df_new = df_new.reset_index()
    ###but it didn't change the outcome
    df_new = df_new.set_index('Year')

    # df_new['Betty Jo Mcneece Receiving Home'].astype('float')
    df_new[col[ind]] = df_new[col[ind]]

    grouped = df_new.groupby('Season', sort=False)

    rowlength = grouped.ngroups/2                         # fix up if odd number of groups
    fig, axs = plt.subplots(figsize=(15,10),
                            nrows=2, ncols=int(rowlength),     # fix as above
                            gridspec_kw=dict(hspace=0.4))#, sharex='col', sharey='row') # Much control of gridspec


    targets = zip(grouped.groups.keys(), axs.flatten())
    for i, (key, ax) in enumerate(targets):

        ax.plot(grouped.get_group(key)[col[ind]], marker='o', color='orange')
        ax.set_ylim(0,)
        ax.set_yticks(ax.get_yticks(),size=12)
        #ax.set_xlim(2009,2020)
        ax.set_xticks(np.arange(2009,2020,1))
        ax.set_xticklabels(ax.get_xticks(), rotation = 45, size=12)
        ax.set_title(key)

    fig.suptitle("%s"%col[ind], fontsize=30)
    plt.show()
```

[image: Organized months example]